# How to parse html file using clojure?

Tags: html, clojure

I'm new to clojure and I need some examples. Please show me how to parse html file using clojure?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628958/good-clojure-code-examples

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) is a great tool for this. In short:

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

(defn fetch-page [url]
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)))
```

[Here](https://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial/) is a nice tutorial on using it both as a scraper/parser and as a template engine:

[Here](https://github.com/miles-no/MilesCampHackatonScraper/blob/master/src/miles_hackaton_scraper/core.clj) is a short example of scraping a page.

Another option is [clj-tagsoup](https://github.com/nathell/clj-tagsoup). Enlive also uses tagsoup, but in addition has a pluggable parser so you can add support for other parsers.

Comment: Can I parse html file without envile or another parser, using only clojure?

Comment: Well, you can get the content of a web page as a string by only doing: (slurp "http://www.example.com"), but in order to work with the content in a manageable way you need a parser (like enlive).

Answer (score 4):

Clojure's [xml](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.xml) [parsing](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.xml/parse) library is there for you.

> Parses and loads the source s, which can be a File, InputStream or
>   String naming a URI. Returns a tree of the xml/element struct-map,
>   which has the keys :tag, :attrs, and :content. and accessor fns tag,
>   attrs, and content. Other parsers can be supplied by passing
>   startparse, a fn taking a source and a ContentHandler and returning a
>   parser

Or use [enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive), it's framework fully on clojure or use Java based [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

HTML Parsers

- [clj-tagsoup](https://github.com/nathell/clj-tagsoup) clj
- [Crouton](https://github.com/weavejester/crouton) clj
- [Hickory](https://github.com/davidsantiago/hickory) clj cljs
- [Tupelo](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) clj cljs
- [Webmine](https://github.com/tol/webmine) clj

source - https://www.clojure-toolbox.com